# How to create a custom dynamic DNS solution?

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

You all probably know commercial dynamic DNS providers like dyndns.org or no-ip.com.

But how to create a similar service for just a handful of machines?

What server software would be best suited for such a setup (under Linux)?

Advantages:

- the service would be under your control
- no tracking by some opaque company

Minimal requirements:

Probably something like: you own at least one host machine with a static IP, a domain and your domain provider let you configure DNS records.

Clients:

A few machines that are connected via cable/DSL and only get dynamic IP addresses on each dial-up and/or every x hours.

Comment: Look at the German WiKi on DynDNS [http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DynDNS]. The English WiKi is not worth visiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on how similar to DynDNS.org this service should be.

For your seemmingly small use case I would propably set up a combined DHCP/bind-server (with Linux - what else).

The DHCP server is able to update your DNS-server that acts as primary server for a subdomain of "your" provider-domain. Make sure to register that subdomain with a short TTL or register your sub-domain at your provider as "to be forwarded to".

The more complicated part is assigning fixed names for your DSL-machines. Do you control them/have a fixed number with not changing fixed MAC-adresses?

The lease-time for DHCP should be > 1 day, so the same client gets the same IP+name  again.

**Update:** I found someone with exactly your problem and the solution [here](http://sacrifunk.milton.com/index.php/2007/02/18/diy_dynamic_dns).
There is a Open Source project named [GNUdip](http://gnudip2.sourceforge.net/) that should fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Ok, the outline is clear - but what about the details? e.g. with which command you update a DNS server, what DNS record to set such that a host acts as a primary server etc. - how to configure 'to be forwarded to'? Regarding the DSL-machines - they have fixed MAC-addresses and I control them.

Comment: Since you have a number of fixed MAC-adresses you can use HCP mode - i.e. you can specify which MAC-address should get which IP (and thus name). In this combination you can even used "normal", fixed DNS entries. Then you don`t have to fight your way through putting up your own DNS server that accepts dynamic updates (which is just a simple option for the DHCPD).

Comment: well, the point is that the (external) IPs of the DSL-machines are dynamic ...

Comment: So the DSL-machines do not dial up your server to get an IP, but just to change their CNAME to a differnent IP in you DNS subdomain. This should be doable with a (faked) DHCP-request to your server, too. Problem is that this has to be an IP level request - not Ethernet. So you need some kind of wrapper there (on client and server side).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [GnuDIP](http://gnudip2.sourceforge.net/gnudip-www) Project.
It is old but with a little work it should perform

Answer (score 1):

You assign an IP address using DHCP conf bound to a mac address and have their names setup in either the hosts file or your in internal view with acl in `named.conf` bind9 (named)/dhcpd daemons. Or if you have a real dial-in you want to consider a pppd solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own DDNS service using shared web hosting on direct admin.
The no-ip and dyndns protocol are very similar. Follow them with the direct admin command `CMD_API_DNS_CONTROL`.

Unfortunately routers does not support "common ddns protocol".
Still updating ip ends with just calling:

```
wget --user <user> --password <password> "https://ddns.XXX.XXX/nic/update/?hostname=rrr.ddns.XXX.XXX"
```

where the password and user can be hardcoded in the scripts.